# How do I set the z-index of a specific select2

Tags: css, jquery-select2, outsystems

I am trying to set the z-index of a specific select2 component on my screen as it needs to be higher than the Top_Menu, and then the rest of the select2's z-index I want to be 0. 
so I have written this

```
.Top_Menu.OSInline > .select2-container { 
    z-index: 50 !important;
}

.select2-container { 
    z-index: 0;
}
```

and when I look at chromes inspect element, the z-index has been applied as expected, but when using the widget it still has a z-index of 0 as it still goes under the .Top_Menu (Top_Menu's z-index is currently set to 2)

Comment: _"If you need any more information from me then please let me know."_ - we already did: [ask]

Comment: Is the first selector correct and does your element have a position value other than (the default) `position: static`? You can't have z-index on an element without position relative, fixed, absolute, etc.

Comment: Hi, yes the element has a position: relative. What I should probably add is that the style for select2 is somewhere else and I am just overriding it.

Comment: Try to turn the order you have above or make it simple and add an additional class to the element.

Comment: Have you made any progress? Also, make sure that the containing element is set to "display:relative"

Answer (score 0):

`select2-container{z-index: 0;}` is never used (even though it is loaded later) because `select2-container` has lower *specificity* than `.Top_Menu.OSInline > .select2-container`.

For example,

```css
/*Loaded first, Most Specific*/
div.MoreThan > div.ALittleSpecific {
  color: blue;
}

/*Loaded second, Kindof Specific*/
div.ALittleSpecific {
  color: red;
}

/*Loaded last, Least Specific*/
div {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="MoreThan">
<div class="ALittleSpecific">
  Specificity Trumps Load Order
</div>
</div>
```

Increase specificity for your second .select2-container (either with a new class or more explicitly recognized parents, and you should be able to less-confusingly work out a solution.